# How to ensure single action in multithreaded JPA application

Tags: multithreading, hibernate, tomcat, jpa

I have a multithreaded application (running in a servlet container) with a JPA/hibernate backend. This application allows to retrieve documents via simple URLs. Upon the first time a document is downloaded (i.e. a request for a specific URL is received), the application should send a notification message via email and mark the document as retrieved in the database.

What is the proper way to ensure, that only a single email is sent per document? Since the link to retrieve the document might be clicked multiple times, there might be parallel transactions (in different threads). Theses transactions would see their respective results only when committed.

Answer (score 1):

Since sending an email is not transactional, I see two possibilities:

- use a global transaction to update the retrieaval status and sens a JMS message indicating that an email must be sent. Optimistic concurrency should be activated on the document entity (using an @Version field). This way, if the transaction fails due to optimistic concurrency checking, the JMS message is not sent. You of course need a JMS listener to ectually send an email when the JMS message is received
- use optimistic locking, and send the email out of the transaction. If the transaction fails due to optimistic locking, the email is not sent. If it succeeds, the email is sent.

Or you just don't care, and assume that concurrent first-time downloads will be very exceptional. You might thus receive two emails instead of one very exceptionally, and you just delete the superfluous email in this case.